# How to redirect error messages to log file in a shell script

Tags: unix, shell-script

I am executing below command to store matching files/directories however if i dont find any match then im getting error messages on console

```
 matching_files=`ls -d $log_dir/$pattern`

ls: cannot access /logs/archive_file*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /logs/archive_dir*: No such file or directory
```

I want to log these errors in a file instead of displaying on console
How to achieve this in shell script?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `ls` at all. I assume you're using bash. We'll just be using the shell globbing characters to store the files in an array:

```
matching_files=( $log_dir/$pattern )
if [[ "${#matching_files[@]}" -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "no files found"
else
    echo "I found these matching files:"
    printf "%s\n" "${matching_files[@]}"
fi

for file in "${matching_files[@]}"; do
    do_something_with "$file"
done
```

Comment: Its not storing all the matching files in matching_files variable if we use  matching_files=( $log_dir/$pattern )

Comment: Can you show an example where files are found with `ls` but are missing here?

Comment: matching_files=(/logs/magsubmit_*)  then  echo $matching_files will give only single file -> 
/logs/magsubmit_dir_1.log  though there are 4 matching files in logs dir

Comment: The matching_files variable is an *array*. `echo $matching_files` will only show the first element. Do `printf "%s\n" "${matching_files[@]}"` to see them all